# Рандомно вытащить несколько значений из txt файла

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Есть txt файл:

```
rama
mama
papa
deda
koza
dama
repa
и т.д.
```

Надо рандомно вытащить оттуда 3 слова, но так, чтобы первое слово было как в txt файле, на примере этого rama, а остальные 2 слова любые, но чтоб уже не повторялись со старыми словами.

Подскажите пожалуйста как все это реализовать на Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random
with open('source.txt', 'r') as source:
   l = source.readlines()
   word1 = l[0]
   word2 = ''
   word3 = ''
   while True:
      word2 = l[random.randint(1, len(l) - 1)]
      if word2 != word1:
         break
   while True:
      word3 = l[random.randint(1, len(l) - 1)]
      if word3 != word1 and word3 != word2:
         break
   print(word1, word2, word3)
```

1) Предполагается, что в файле одно слово в каждой строке.

2) Уйдет в бесконечный цикл, если в файле нет трех различных слов.

3) Крайне неэффективно по памяти при большом объеме исходного файла.

Comment: 4) Поскольку `randint` работает с отрезком [a;b], при получении значения равного `len(l)`, Вы получите ошибку выхода за диапазон. Из документации: `random.randint(a, b)` => return a random integer N such that `a <= N <= b`.

Comment: @AlexKrass, спасибо, поправил. Почему то считал, что randint аналогично range работает.

Comment: как-то вы совсем сложно подходите к решению: `words = [next(source)] + random.sample(set(source), 2)`

Comment: @jfs, ну да, по кол-ву кода Ваш вариант явно короче и элегантней). Вопрос в цене `set(source)` по сравнению с моими циклами...

Comment: @andy.37: как `set()` так и `readlines()` читают весь файл.

Comment: @jfs, насколько я понимаю, `set` должен сделать из списка множество без повторений, я даже не уверен, что это `O(n)`. По памяти наши варианты неэффективны одинаково (Ваш чуть лучше, вероятно). Зато мой будет чудно работать для файла из 10000 строк с тремя различными словами...

Comment: `source` у вас это файл, а не список (иначе бы `next(source)` не работал). Гарантированно (если специальным образом ввод не сконфигурирован  (`PYTHONHASHSEED`) — случайно так не получится с заметной вероятностью) что амортизированное O(n) время. Меня больше смущает излишняя многословность  вашего кода без веских оснований: нужно писать самый  простой код, который справляется с задачей — всё остальное вторично.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34190/discussion-between-andy-37-and-jfs).

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы прочитать первую строчку и выбрать ещё две случайные строчки из небольшого файла:

```
#!/urs/bin/env python3
import random

with open('input.txt') as file:
    lines = [next(file)] + random.sample(list(file), 2)
print(*map(str.strip, lines))
```

`next(file)` читает первую строчку из файла (файлы являются итераторами над строками в Питоне). [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample) выбирает пару элементов из списка без замещений. Если слова во входном файле не повторяются, то результат всегда содержит уникальные слова.

---

Если слова могут повторяться в файле, то можно использовать
[`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), чтобы только уникальные слова остались:

```
#!/urs/bin/env python3
import random

with open('input_with_dups.txt') as file:
    first_word = next(file).strip()
    words = set(map(str.strip, file)) - {first_word} # unique words
print(first_word, *random.sample(words, 2)) #NOTE: use random.sample()
                                            #to avoid relying on
                                            #PYTHONHASHSEED behavior
```

В этом случае, вероятность, что слово выбрано, не зависит от того
как часто оно встречается в файле—все слова (кроме первого) имеют
одинаковый вес.

[`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)
используется, чтобы удалить пробелы из входных строк, так чтобы в
каждой строке только само слово осталось, иначе `'word'`, `'word\n'`,
или `'word '` рассматривались бы как разные слова.

---

Если файл большой, но содержит только различающиеся слова, то можно использовать `reservoir_sample()` функцию, которая реализует  [линейный алгоритм R](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling):

```
#!/urs/bin/env python3
with open('input.txt') as file:
    lines = [next(file)] + reservoir_sample(file, 2)
print(*map(str.strip, lines))
```

Это решение не читает весь файл в память сразу и поэтому может работать даже для больших файлов. Где `reservoir_sample()`:

```
import itertools
import random

def reservoir_sample(iterable, k,
                     randrange=random.randrange, shuffle=random.shuffle):
    """Select *k* random elements from *iterable*.

    Use O(n) Algorithm R https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling
    """
    it = iter(iterable)
    sample = list(itertools.islice(it, k))  # fill the reservoir
    if len(sample) < k:
        raise ValueError("Sample larger than population")
    shuffle(sample)
    for i, item in enumerate(it, start=k+1):
        j = randrange(i) # random [0..i)
        if j < k:
            sample[j] = item # replace item with gradually decreasing probability
    return sample
```

Вероятность выбора произвольной строчки в
файле постоянна и равна `k / n`, где `n`—кол-во строк в файле.

---

В общем случае (если слова могут повторяться во входом файле и он
может быть большим). Необходимо модифицировать `reservoir_sample()`
алгоритм, чтобы только ещё невыбранные элементы рассматривались:

```
#!/urs/bin/env python3
import itertools
import random


def choose_uniq(iterable, k, chosen, randrange=random.randrange):
    j0 = len(chosen)
    it = (x for x in iterable if x not in chosen)
    for x in itertools.islice(it, k):  # NOTE: add one by one
        chosen.append(x)
    if len(chosen) < (j0 + k):
        raise ValueError("Sample larger than population")
    for i, item in enumerate(it, start=k + 1):
        j = randrange(i)  # random [0..i)
        if j < k:  # replace item with gradually decreasing probability
            chosen[j0 + j] = item

with open('input_with_dups.txt') as file:
    chosen_words = [next(file).strip()]  # first word
    choose_uniq(map(str.strip, file), 2, chosen_words)
print(*chosen_words)
```

`(x for x in iterable if x not in chosen)` отсеивает уже выбранные
элементы. Это работает, так как элементы генерируются «лениво»: по
одному. Так как `k == 2` в этом случае, то `x not in chosen` это
быстрая операция даже для списка. Для больших `к`, можно `set` тип в
этом выражении использовать, чтобы получить `O(1)` поведение.

`choose_uniq()` не ведёт себя как `random.sample()`, поэтому
`shuffle()` убран. Получающееся распределение не совсем равномерное: в
зависимости от порядка строк в исходном файле, часто повторяющаяся
строка может быть выбрана чаще чем если бы только уникальные слова
рассматривались бы (результат отличается от
`set(map(str.strip, file)) - {first_word}` решения).

Если требуется равномерное распределение (все уникальные слова
выбираются с одинаковой вероятностью), то для больших файлов,
не помещающихся в памяти, можно использовать [внешнюю
сортировку](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14465154/4279), что позже
позволит отсеять дубликаты без дополнительных затрат памяти (в `O(1)`
памяти), например, используя
[`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
что в свою очередь позволит использовать снова `reservoir_sample()`
без изменений.

---

Если не требуется строго равномерное распределение, то чтобы не читать весь потенциально большой файл (для скорости), можно выбирать слова со случайной позиции в файле. Для удобства можно использовать [`mmap` модуль](https://docs.python.org/library/mmap), который позволяет обращаться с файлом как со строкой
(последовательность байтов), даже если размер файла больше доступной памяти:

```
#!/urs/bin/env python3
import locale
import mmap
import random
import re

with open('input_with_dups.txt', 'rb') as file, \
        mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
    first_nonspace_pos = re.search(br'\S', s).start()  # skip leading space
    chosen = set([get_word(s, first_nonspace_pos), b''])  # get 1st word
    while len(chosen) != 4:  # add two more random non-empty words
        chosen.add(get_word(s, random.randrange(len(s))))
encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding(False)
print(*[w.decode(encoding) for w in chosen if w])
```

где `get_word()` возвращает слово из строки около указанной позиции в файле:

```
def get_word(s, position, newline=b'\n'):
    """Return a word from a line in *s* at *position*."""
    i = s.rfind(newline, 0, position)  # find newline on the left
    start = (i + 1) if i != -1 else 0
    i = s.find(newline, position)  # find newline on the right
    end = i if i != -1 else len(s)
    return s[start:end].strip()  # a space is not part of a word, strip it
```

В файле могут быть пустые (содержащие только пробелы строки)—код с
`first_nonspace_index` и `b''` позволяет избежать выбора пустого
слова. Код предполагает, что во входном файле больше двух различных
слов иначе возможен бесконечный цикл. Юникодный пробелы (такие как
U+00A0) не рассматриваются.

Вероятность выбора слова в этом случае может зависеть от длины
слов, частоты их повторения в файле и даже от
используемой кодировки (то есть распределение неравномерное).

Comment: на большом файле возможно читать кусками, отбрасываем первую и последнюю строку из куска, т.к. может быть не полной, остальные стандартным random.sample из set

Comment: @Igor не вижу как это поможет выбрать слова случайно, не нарушая равномерного распределения (если комментарий о `choose_uniq()` случае). Или вы надеетесь улучшить производительность  `reservoir_sample()` решения? (которое вероятно ограничено только скоростью диска—IO bound). Попробуйте в виде ответа представить решение для ясности.

Comment: В исходной задаче о равномерном распределении ничего не было сказано, приведение данных к нормализованному виду считаем что не требуется. Иначе нужно понимать, нужны ли нам числа или их удаляем, сколько букв в слове и т.п. В задаче указана только необходимость выборки 3 слов из файла = строки. Если файл огромный то построчное чтение не требуется в полном объеме. Погрешность в выборке будет допустима.

Comment: @Igor фраза "рандомно выбрать" подразумевает равномерное распределение иначе можно было бы просто прочитать три первых попавшихся различающихся слова из файла. Не нужно игнорировать условия *без оснований* и *не упоминая что вы их игнорируете. Ещё раз: что вы хотели достичь (скорость, простоту кода)?

Comment: больше простоту чем скорость.

Comment: @Igor: попробуйте реализовать ваше предложение, перечислив явно когда предположения, используемые в решении, и посмотрите насколько код простым получится (или нет).

Comment: Посмотрел, но задача не совсем ясна, полный перебор всех строк в файле или выдернуть кусок текста размером в 50мб и сделать выборку из него. Решения разные.

Answer (score 2):

```
f = open('111.txt', 'r')
first = next(f)
other = set(f) - {first}
result = first + other.pop() + other.pop()
print(result)
```

rama

koza

mama

Comment: спасибо, поправил

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

f = open("data.txt").readlines()
first = {f[0]}  # первая строка
lists = set(f) - first
if len(lists) > 1:
    print(first.union(random.sample(lists, 2)))
else:
    print('в файле нет 3 разных строк')
```

Comment: Это неверно, если во вводе есть повторяющиеся слова или если строки разнятся только пробелами (невидно глазу может быть). Плохо игнорировать ошибки ввода, если ввод слишком маленький программа должна громко ломаться, если явно других требований не указано. Дважды читать файл нет необходимости.

Comment: Программа не должна уходить в бесконечный цикл, как в отмеченном варианте, громко ломаться - архитектурно правильно, но на реальных данных проще try except с игнором всего что не подходит, особенно в части дорвеев.

Comment: Я не вижу бесконечных циклов в этом ответе. Ещё раз: решение неверное, если во входном файле слова могут повторяться.

Comment: random.sample - выбор не повторяющихся, значит может повториться только с первым. Здесь согласен. По бесконечному циклу, проверяется 3 элемента, но если в файле 2 не повторяющихся, то решения при том алгоритме нет.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду решение из [@andy.37 ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481688/23044)? я вам говорю: "ваш ответ неправильный". вы мне говорите: "а вот там есть другой ответ, в котором решение не всегда работает" (разница в том, что в andy.37 ответе *явно* сказано, когда его решение не работает). К чему вы упоминаете решение из другого ответа здесь?

Comment: @jfs, код подправил, теперь должно быть все верно. Упоминал потому что в разговоре речь шла сразу о двух темах. Приведение строк к общему не рассматриваю как необходимость в данном случае.