# Поиск паттерна (последовательность байт) в файле (несколько Гб) в Питоне 2

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Здравствуйте! Необходимо осуществить поиск pattern'a в файле любого формата. В качестве pattern'a может выступать какая-либо последовательность байт. Как это можно сделать при использовании Python?

Comment: Если дополнительных ограничений нет, то `pattern in s`, где s это mmap, скажет есть ли pattern в файле. `s.find(pattern)` возвращает позицию pattern в файле (смещение в байтах). Вот [пример кода с mmap (в конце ответа)—выбор случайных слов из файла](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/552028/23044).

Comment: Есть еще одно ограничение - размер файла, который может  быть несколько Гб

Comment: Решение с mmap работает и для многострочного pattern, для pattern  размером от одного байта  до всех байт в файле и для больших файлов, которые в памяти не помещаются.

Comment: import mmap

def searchPattern(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r+b') as file:
        map = mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0)


def main():
    searchPattern('C:\\Temp\\src\\squid.log')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Comment: WindowsError: [Error 8]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы узнать содержит ли файл возможно многострочный pattern размеров от одного байта до всех байт в файле:

```
#!/urs/bin/env python2
"""Usage: find-pattern <pattern> <filename>"""
import mmap
import sys
from contextlib import closing

pattern, filename = sys.argv[1:]
with open(filename, 'rb', 0) as file, \
     closing(mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)) as s:
    sys.exit(s.find(pattern) == -1)
```

Скрипт возвращает ноль, если найден `pattern` и `1` иначе.
`mmap` поддерживает и файлы больше доступной памяти.

Если размер файла больше адресного пространства (на 32-битной системе может встретиться), то можно mmap по частям делать и проверять `len(pattern)` части на границе кусков руками. В этом случае, возможно вариант с `file.read(chunksize)` удобней напрямую использовать без mmap.