# WindowsError: [Error 8]—ошибка при использовании mmap с файлом ~2GB

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
import mmap
import contextlib
import sys

print sys.version
with open('C:\\bigfile.log', 'r+') as f:
    with contextlib.closing(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)) as m:
        print m.readline().rstrip()
```

При использовании mmap возникает ошибка WindowsError: [Error 8], которая говорит о нехватке памяти. 
Почему возникает такая ошибка и как ее можно исправить?

P.S. Hазмер файла ~2 Гб

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Поиск паттерна (последовательность байт) в файле (несколько Гб) в Питоне 2](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606675/23044)

Comment: связанный Питон баг: [mmap on Windows can mishandle files larger than sys.maxsize](http://bugs.python.org/issue16743)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте 64 битную версию питона. Дело в том, что у 32 битных приложений размер памяти ограничен.

Я как-то открывал `json` файл размером 1 гб и была такая же проблема.

Comment: Тут несколько факторов: ограничение 32-битного адресного пространства (что отличается от доступной памяти) плюс как конкретная реализация Питона работает (см. баг наверху).