# Как выбрать текст из файла между двумя известными строками?

Tags: python, строки, текст

Есть текстовый файл, необходимо выбрать из него некоторое кол-во строк, текст всегда разный, но всегда есть заранее известных две строки, но текст до них, между ними и после нет. Ну как пример:

```
Я вас любил: любовь еще, быть может,
В душе моей угасла не совсем;
Но пусть она вас больше не тревожит;
Я не хочу печалить вас ничем.
Я вас любил безмолвно, безнадежно,
То робостью, то ревностью томим;
Я вас любил так искренно, так нежно,
Как дай вам бог любимой быть другим. :)
```

и из этого допустим нам известны строки: "Но пусть она вас больше не тревожит;" и "То робостью, то ревностью томим;".
Необходимо забрать их и то что между ними, остальное нам ненужно.

Comment: не самое эффективное решение, но вполне рабочее `excerpt = re.search(r'(Но пусть она вас больше не тревожит.*То робостью, то ревностью томим;)'s, text).group(1)`

Answer (score 5):

Если известные строки даны в `start`, `end` переменных, то чтобы получить срез состоящий из этих строк и всё что между ними:

```
result = text[text.index(start):text.index(end)+len(end)]
```

Предполагая, что `end` встречается в `text` только после `start`.

К примеру:

```
>>> text = '..abc..'
>>> start = 'a'
>>> end = 'c'
>>> text[text.index(start):text.index(end)+len(end)]
'abc'
```

Можно регулярные выражения использовать:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('{}.*?{}'.format(*map(re.escape, [start, end])), text, re.M).group()
'abc'
```

Чтобы не загружать весь файл в память, можно использовать `mmap` и байты. См.

- [Поиск паттерна (последовательность байт) в файле (несколько Гб) в Питоне 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606675/23044)
- [Python multi-line pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25942181/4279)

Comment: `i = text.index(start); result = text[i:text.index(end, i) + len(end)]`

Comment: @andreymal если уж несколько строчек заводить, то для корректности можно сразу regex использовать (как в `sed '/start_pattern/,/end_pattern/` или perl flip-flop операторе). Много вариаций возможно в зависимости от требований: разрешённый ввод, производительность, первое вхождение/самое последнее, итд. Можно к примеру text.find() использовать и проверять возвращаемый индекс вместо выбрасывания исключения.

Comment: А почему `*map(re.escape, [start, end])`, а не `re.escape(start), re.escape(end)`? Это python way такой?

Comment: Ну и кстати, в [Чтение сегмента файла в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693040/) задача на поиск всех вхождений, что не полностью решается с помощью `re.search().group()`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin 1- map(re.escape, намекает, что *одно* преобразование (что строки буквально должны восприниматься, а не как регулярные выражения). [Часто приходится map(re.escape, использовать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33411504/4279) Для списка из двух переменных можно и по отдельности вызвать. 2- я вижу "чтение сегмента" (а не чтение сегментов) в заголовке.  Автор может отредактировать вопрос, что несколько вхождений интересует или мне указать на цитату из вопроса, которую я не внимательно прочитал, тогда переоткрою ([mmap + re.findall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20024735/4279) можно)

Answer (score 2):

```
# если имеются виду строки разделенные '\n', можно не читать файл целиком
def get_inside_lines(file: iter, start_line: str, end_line: str) -> iter:
    for line in file:
        if line == start_line:
            yield line
            for line in file:
                yield line
                if line == end_line:
                    return

r = ''.join(get_inside_lines(open('111.txt', encoding='utf-8'),
                             'Но пусть она вас больше не тревожит;\n',
                             'То робостью, то ревностью томим;\n'))
```

Comment: Если построчно искать, то можно: `itertools.takewhile(end.__ne__, dropwhile(start.__ne__, file))` что возвращает start + все строчки до end (не включая). `s.__ne__` означает "not equal": `lambda line: s != line`.

Comment: в dropwhile в результат попадает лишняя строка start

Comment: читайте вопрос внимательней: _"забрать **их и** то что между ними"_

Comment: тогда не попадает end :)

Comment: поэтому мой комментарий *явно* содержит: *"до end (не включая)"*