# Поиск нескольких подстрок в строке и их вывод

Tags: python, search

Уважаемые знатоки, всем здравствуйте. Совсем недавно стал постигать python и передо мной встала срочная задача:
Найти в строке часть слова и вывести его.
Самое сложное то, что нужно учесть три возможных варианта.
Пример:

Есть несколько строк:

```
abc_dddddd/hhhh_ttt
ccca_fsefs/esfsef_fff
abc_dddawd/hserf_ttt
ccb_dadw/dawd_daddd
ccb_fasefsf/sfsef_rttt
```

Мне нужно осуществить поиск по трем вариантам (`abc, ccca, ccb`). Использую  цикл:

```
while ttt>0: 
    try: displayName = build_info['displayName'] 
        if 'abc' in displayName: 
            print("true1") 
        if 'ccca' in displayName: 
            print("true2") 
        if 'ccb' in displayName: 
            print("true3")
```

Не могу понять, как выводить все значения, использую конструкцию `if-if`, но заходит только в первое значение, а дальше по другим условия не просматривает.

Как быть, спасайте!

И еще сразу дополнительный вопрос.
Есть внутри строки, после символа / и перед символом # необходимое подстрока. Как ее тоже напечатать.

Пример

```
abc_dddddd/hhhh_ttt#1
ccca_fsefs/esfsef_fff#33
abc_dddawd/hserf_ttt#2
ccb_dadw/dawd_daddd#22
ccb_fasefsf/sfsef_rttt#55
```

Нужно найти все строки между / и # и вывести их вместе с первой подстрокой.
Спасибо!

Comment: старайтесь одним вопросом в каждом  Stack Overflow вопросе ограничиваться. Вопрос «как найти подстроку между разделителями» вы можете отдельно задать (примеры: [Чтение сегментов из файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693040/23044), [Как выбрать текст из файла между двумя известными строками?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/622391/23044)). После этого, если вам не ясно как объединить решения этих задач, то задайте ещё один вопрос специально об этом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы вывести какие подстроки из указанных встречаются в строке, можно регулярные выражения использовать:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('abc|ccca|ccb', build_info['displayName'])
['abc', 'ccca', 'abc', 'ccb', 'ccb']
```