# Анализ большого бинарного файла

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Есть бинарный файл (несколько ГБ), размер которого превышает объем оперативной памяти. Как можно его обработать при помощи mmap и multiprocessing?

Comment: Не читать целиком в память, а читать только те куски, которые нужны - не вариант?

Comment: Вопрос в том, что заранее неизвестно какие куски нужны

Comment: Ничто не мешает узнавать это в процессе работы и читать. Даже если файл нужно будет в итоге прочитать целиком, это можно сделать по кускам.

Comment: Специфика задачи подразумевает, что необходимо анализировать весь файл целиком без разрыва(необходимо искать куски, удовлетворяющие регулярке)

Comment: А какая максимальная длина фрагмента, удовлетворяющего регулярке?

Comment: Фрагмент не более 30 символов

Comment: В таком случае читать больше 30 байт за раз и не нужно...

Comment: Но тогда придется использовать механизм плавающего окна, что снизит скорость

Comment: Создаете несколько потоков. В каждом потоке читаете часть файла (например 1 поток с 0 линии по 10000, 2 c 10000 по 20000, и т.д.), результат роботы помещете в очередь. Очередь читаете в главном потоке. Проблемы?

Comment: Вы можете regex к mmap применить (если система 64-битная, то сразу весь файл как mmap можно открыть). [Поиск паттерна (последовательность байт) в файле (несколько Гб) в Питоне 2](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606675/23044)

Comment: Пример re + mmap: [How to read tokens without reading whole line or file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20019503/4279)